# I'm trying to deploy to vercel but getting this error: Command "npm install" exited with 1

Tags: deployment, vercel

```
I'm trying to deploy to vercel but getting this error:
`
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-alert@7.0.3
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=0.14.0" from @hypnosphi/create-react- 
context@0.3.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@hypnosphi/create-react-context
npm ERR!     @hypnosphi/create-react-context@"^0.3.1" from react-
```

popper@1.3.11
npm ERR!     node_modules/mdbreact/node_modules/react-popper
npm ERR!       react-popper@"^1.3.7" from mdbreact@5.2.0
npm ERR!       node_modules/mdbreact
npm ERR!         mdbreact@"^5.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   27 more (@react-aria/ssr, @restart/hooks, @restart/ui, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.1 || ^17" from react-alert@7.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/react-alert
npm ERR!   react-alert@"^7.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.1 || ^17" from react-alert@7.0.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-alert
npm ERR!     react-alert@"^7.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency
resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-05-04T12_39_34_043Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-05-04T12_39_34_043Z-debug-0.log
Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1
Deployment completed
BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "npm install" exited with 1
`

I have tried many ways but no change
This is my link github: https://github.com/phonglh1/react-department.git